# Cloudflare Workers Redirection Setting Cookie Only on 1st visit, then Respect Session Language

Tags: redirect, cookies, geolocation, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am interested in redirecting users based on their geolocation. I decided to use Cloudflare Workers for this reason. I read and implemented the [Country Redirection on Workers](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/geoip-redirection-worker/14414/3) successfully, but there is one more thing for me to resolve. The redirection works 100% and all the time, as it is supposed to do. Ideally, however, I would like the redirection to only work on 1st visit, then respect the language session. This issue has also been reported in [here](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/country-redirection/140711/8). The solution seems to be the use of appropriate cookies. More specifically, one of the comments mentions: “You could use cookies, which you set in the response object and then check for in the request object.”

I would appreciate it if anyone can pinpoint exactly how to set this cookie in order to achieve my goal and overcome this issue.

Thank you very much.

**Here is my Workers code:**

```
//these countries go to /sg
var sg_countries = ['SG', 'TH', 'MY', 'VN', 'RI', 'RP', 'LA', 'BN'];

//these go to /jp
var jp_countries = ['JP'];

//these go to /gr
var gr_countries = ['GR'];

//these go to /kr
var kr_countries = ['KR'];

//these countries go to /zh-sg
var zh_sg_countries = ['TW', 'HK', 'CN'];

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
event.respondWith(Redirect(event.request))
})

function inArray(needle, haystack) {
var length = haystack.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (haystack[i] == needle) return true;
}
return false;
}

function mapCountry(country_code) {
if (inArray(country_code, sg_countries)) {
    return 'https://ofdreams.com/sg';
}
if (inArray(country_code, jp_countries)) {
    return 'https://ofdreams.com/jp';
}
if (inArray(country_code, gr_countries)) {
    return 'https://ofdreams.com/gr';
}
if (inArray(country_code, kr_countries)) {
    return 'https://ofdreams.com/kr';
}
if (inArray(country_code, zh_sg_countries)) {
    return 'https://ofdreams.com/zh-sg';
}

//everyone else gets US
return 'https://ofdreams.com';
}

/**
* Fetch and log a given request object
* @param {Request} request
*/
async function Redirect(request) {

var url = new URL(request.url);

console.log("This is URL" + url);

correctHost = mapCountry(request.headers.get('CF-IPCountry'));

console.log("This is correct Host" + correctHost);

return new Response('', {
status: 301,
headers: {
'Location': correctHost
}
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your response with

```
return new Response('', {
    status: 301,
    headers: {
    'Location': 'https://www.kshitij-joshi.com/xyz',
    'Set-Cookie' : 'name=value; domain=example.com; Secure; HttpOnly; Max-Age=NUMBER'
    }
})

This cookie will be sent by the browser on all requests to all subdomains of your domain for all subsequent requests. The cookie will be available to your worker as a 'Cookie' request header.

Note: You can only set cookies for your domain.
```